# Good metric / method to evaluate balanced multiclass classification when some classes are more similar than others?

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, multi-class

Surely I'm not the first person trying to do this, but can't find a good answer (probably because I'm not searching with the right terms).

I have a problem with 10 balanced classes (0-9) where the error is less important the closer the predicted class is to the actual class (e.g. if true class is 2, I'd rather classify it as 3 than as 8). Essentially, I'd like the confussion matrix to be as centered on the diagonal as possible.

[image: Confussion matrix]

Is there a specific metric/technique that is used in these cases? If so, is it implemented in sklearn or similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your variable ordinal like low/medium/high? (A movie-style “star rating” counts as ordinal.)

Comment: Yes it is. It's a product quality index (0 would be worst quality, 9 would be best quality).

Comment: There are specific methods for doing ordinal regression, since, as you’ve noticed, ordinal variables are kind of a hybrid of numerical and categorical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the [root mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) work? You give more penalty to classes predicted far from the truth. E.g.

```
rmse <- function(predicted, true) {
    sqrt(sum((predicted - true)^2) / length(predicted))
}

rmse(c(1,1,2,2,3,3), c(1,1,2,2,4,4))
[1] 0.577

rmse(c(1,1,2,2,4,5), c(1,1,2,2,4,4))
[1] 0.408
```